# Как получиться значения из массива только кратные определенному значению?

Tags: javascript

```js
// Исходный массив
let arr = [
  1312.9,
  1313.0,
  1313.1,
  1313.2,
  1313.3,
  1313.4,
  1313.5,
  1313.6,
  1313.7,
];

// Из исходного массива сделать новый массив где значения кратны 0.2
let newarr = [
  1313.0,
  1313.2,
  1313.4,
  1313.6,
];

console.log(newarr);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Универсальный метод для работы с любыми числами и делителями

```js
// Исходный массив
let arr = [
  1312.9, 1313.0, 1313.1, 1313.2,
  1313.3, 1313.4, 1313.5, 1313.6,
  1313.7, 1313.8, 1314, 1315,
  1316, 1317, 1318, 1319,
  1320, 1321, 1322, 1323,
  1324, 1325, 1326, 1327,
  1328, 1329, 1330, 1330.1,
  1330.2, 1330.3, 1330.4, 1330.5,
  1330.6, 1330.7, 1330.7, 1330.9,
  1331, 1569.03, 1907.00008,
  13.00000007, 45.000007, 90.000000,
  100.77777, 67.33333333, 87, 99999
];

/**
 * @param {number} a
 * @param {number} b
 * @return {{a: *, b: *}|undefined|{a, b}|{a: *, b}}
 */
function mun(a, b, iter = 0) {
  if (Number.isInteger(a) && Number.isInteger(b)) return [a, b];
  return mun(a*10, b*10, ++iter);
}

/**
 * @param {number[]} arr
 * @param {number} divider
 * @return {number[] || boolean}
 */
function finder(arr, divider) {
  if (divider === 0) return false;
  if (divider === 1) return arr;
  return arr.filter(item => {
    const float = mun(item, divider);
    return float[0] % float[1] === 0;
  })
}

console.log('I0', finder(arr, 0.1));
console.log('I1', finder(arr, 0.2));
console.log('I2', finder(arr, 0.3));
console.log('I3', finder(arr, 0.4));
console.log('I4', finder(arr, 0.5));
console.log('I5', finder(arr, 0.6));
console.log('I6', finder(arr, 0.7));
console.log('I7', finder(arr, 0.8));
console.log('I8', finder(arr, 0.9));
console.log('=========================')
console.log('I9', finder(arr, 0));
console.log('I10', finder(arr, 1));
console.log('I11', finder(arr, 2));

console.log('I12', finder(arr, 3));
console.log('I13', finder(arr, 4));
console.log('I14', finder(arr, 5));
console.log('I15', finder(arr, 6));
console.log('I16', finder(arr, 7));
console.log('I17', finder(arr, 8));
console.log('I18', finder(arr, 9));
```

Answer (score 1):

Когда из массива значений нужно получить массив с *некоторыми* исходными значениями - это операция фильтрации.

```js
// Исходный массив
let arr = [
  1312.9,
  1313.0,
  1313.1,
  1313.2,
  1313.3,
  1313.4,
  1313.5,
  1313.6,
  1313.7,
];

const res = arr.filter((item) => {
  return (item * 10) % 2 === 0;
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Исходный массив
let arr = [
  1312.9,
  1313.0,
  1313.1,
  1313.2,
  1313.3,
  1313.4,
  1313.5,
  1313.6,
  1313.7,
];

// Из исходного массива сделать новый массив где значения кратны 0.2
let newarr = [];
for (let i in arr) {
  let value = (Number) ((Math.round(arr[i] / 0.2) * 0.2).toFixed(1));
  if (newarr.indexOf(value) == -1 && arr.indexOf(value) != -1) newarr.push(value);
}

console.log(newarr);
```